# Switching my php coded site to laravel framework

Tags: php, laravel

Hey friends i am  switching from core php to laravel framework and every thing works fine but the main problem is that my old version of site is based on this url pattern

```
https://m.apkleet.com/apk.php?app=garena-contra-returns
```

And my new laravel project url is something like this

```
https://m.apkleet.com/apk/garena-contra-returns
```

And if I change my site to laravel then it effects my seo due to this different url patterns...

**my question is that how to redirect ugly url to laravel url.... Is there anything present in laravel to do this**

Any help or recommendation will highly appreciated...

Comment: Done dude... And Thnx a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your route define, just set your URL to apk.php. Something like this

```
Route::get('apk.php', [YourControllerClass, 'index'])->name('routeName');
```

And to generate the url for HTML, you need to pass `app` in param

```
route('routeName', ["app" => "garena-contra-returns"])
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the anser of my question

```
Route::get('apk.php', function () {
        $apk = $_GET['app'];
        return redirect('apk/'.$apk);
    });
```